# Is it possible to add an XSLT reference to an XML document generated with Java-To-Schema annotation?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, annotations

I have a rest service with a method that returns a list of Reports. Report looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "report")
public class Report {
    private String id;  
    private String time;    

    public Report() {}

    public String getTime() {return time;}
    public void setTime(String time) {this.time = time;}

    public String getId() {return this.id;}    
    public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}    
}
```

How can I put a reference to an XSLT document in here?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference an XSLT stylesheet in your XML document.  See http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp for more details.